# Remove Kafka after jhipster app generation

Tags: jhipster

I wanted to remove Kafka that was generated as part of creating a JHipster app. Is there anyway I can do it automatically? With that being said, if in future I want to change my DB to something else, can I still use JHipster generator to do all the automatic configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Just found out I can modify the .yo-rc.json file and rerun jhipster. If anyone knows of another way please comment.

Comment: It's the usual way, after having edited .yo-rc.json you can either (as you did) use`jhipster --with-entities`or use `jhipster upgrade --force`

Comment: I also needed to delete kafka support, will any of these methods impact my so much addition/modifications to front/backend code? For instance, using react frontend I have many new entities/manually edited root reducer, modified generated entities model files etc.

Answer (score 1):

I ma no sure that this is still relevant but i will give a proposition.

To remove Kafka configuration after jhipster generation you have to remove two  beans

1. A configuration bean KafkaProperties.java inside configuration package
2. A Rest controller bean Invoicebackend3KafkaResource.java inside web.rest package.

To do this you can just comment all annotations on top each class